# Filtering by today's date in Meteor collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a datepicker in my Meteor app. When I insert or update the date into my collection, after creating a variable from the value of the datepicker, I do this:

```
due: moment(new Date(due)).toDate()
```

Which inserts the date into mongo like this:

```
Tue Jun 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

What I want to do is filter out the assignments due "Today" and I am not getting anything data into my template. If I do a find() with no filtering I do get back all tasks. So the template is rendering just I cannot get the filtering right.

This is what I have in my code now.

```
 today: function(){        
    var today = moment().startOf(Date());
    var tomorrow = moment(today).add(1, Date());

    return Items.find({
        due:{
            $gt: today.toDate(),
            $lt: tomorrow.toDate()
        }
    });
},
```

I have also tried to just do this:

```
var today = new Date();
Items.find({
     due:{$eq:{today}
     });
```

What am I doing wrong. Since the datepicker is putting 00:00 for the time could that be affecting the query?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To get the assignments due today you'd need to use `$gte`:

```
due:{
  $gte: today.toDate(),
  $lt: tomorrow.toDate()
}
```

But you say you just want to *exclude* these which means you want to negate this query:

```
due: { $not: {
  $gte: today.toDate(),
  $lt: tomorrow.toDate()
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this example can help you:

```
Template.filmstrip.helpers({
  album() {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
   return photos.find(
     {time: {$gte: today } }, 
     {sort: {time:-1} }
   ).fetch();
  }
});
```

Comment: I thank you for this example. I eventually was able to get this to work in the following manner I set the 'today' var like in your example setting the hours to zero, but the $gte was also giving me future assignments. So what I dis since $eq does not work in minimongo was match the 'due field to the today var. Thanks